# fontenc description OT1, EU1

Tags: fonts, font-encodings

I have a simple question about LaTeX. What does it mean when you write

```
\usepackage[OT1,EU1]{fontenc}
```

and where can I find the description?

---

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\xits{XITS}
\newfontfamily\cursor{TeX Gyre Cursor}
\usepackage[OT1]{fontenc}
\renewcommand\rmdefault{cmr}
\renewcommand\sfdefault{cmss}
\renewcommand\ttdefault{cmtt}
\begin{document}
This is Computer Modern Roman.

\textsf{This is Computer Modern Sans.}

\texttt{This is Computer Modern Typewriter.}

{\xits This is Times-like XITS font.}

{\cursor This is Courier-like TeX Gyre Cursor.}
\end{document}
```

Now I have one more question to find a description of shortcuts for each font, like here? I think it `cmr`, `cmss`, `cmtt`.

Comment: `fontenc` is a general LaTeX package, not a XeTeX one. However, you should _not_ be using it with XeTeX (other than the rather specific internal use by `fontspec`).

Comment: I'm interested in this OT1 and EU1.

Comment: About LaTeX font encoding: http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/doc/encguide.pdf, also: http://www.tex.ac.uk/faq/FAQ-why-inp-font.html and http://www.tex.ac.uk/faq/FAQ-t1enc.html.

Comment: @JakubDrábek Where've you seen this? Really, loading `EU1` directly (in particular) is a bad plan.

Comment: That meant as two different options. I do not know what it is. I know that now.

Comment: You shouldn't load OT1 as last encoding when using xelatex/lualatex - the last encoding is the one active at the begin of the document, and you really don't want OT1 with xelatex. Also don't renewcommand `\rmdefault` etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`OT1`, `EU1` are names of TeX font encoding schemes:

- `OT1` is the original text encoding scheme used by TeX, it stands for "Old (Original) Text 1", more information can be found here: [encguide](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/encguide).
- `EU1` is an experimental encoding scheme for Unicode fonts used by XeTeX, it stands for, what else, "Experimental Unicode 1" (`U` in LaTeX framework refers to "Unknown" though), more information can be found here: [EUenc](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/euenc).

`cmr`, `cmss`, `cmtt` are names of typefaces available in the Computer Modern family:

- `cmr` stands for "Computer Modern Roman".
- `cmss` stands for "Computer Modern Sans Serif".
- `cmtt` stands for "Computer Modern Typewriter".

Information regarding these typefaces can be found in [The TeXbook](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/texbook) and [The METAFONTbook](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/mfbook).

There are also plenty of interest read available on TeX Users Group, like this: [Surviving the TeX font encoding mess](ftp://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/utilities/fontinst/doc/talks/et99-font-tutorial.pdf).